# Is it possible to specify element type for the asList method in Neo4J Java Driver v1.0.3

Tags: java, scala, neo4j

Is it possible to specify the type of a list when using `asList` from the Neo4j driver ?

I am using the Java Driver and trying to convert the Java Datatypes to Scala types.

I want something like this:

```
val srcVersions: List[String] = depLink.get("srcVersions").asList()
```

where `List[String]` is a scala type and `asList()` returns `util.List[AnyRef]`

Either there is something built in the driver to change the `AnyRef` to `String` or I need to iterate through the List to convert each element to a String and then convert the list to scala with `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Thank you.

Comment: Tried that, does not work, I don't think you can do that in scala. But thx for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a bit quick to ask that one. Found the answer by reading the [API doc](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/1.0/).

The `asList` function accepts a `Function[Value, String]` to make the conversion for each element. So first step is to convert to `util.List[String]` and then to use `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to convert to `List[String]`

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val srcVersions: List[String] = depLink.get("srcVersions")
                                       .asList(Values.ofToString)
                                       .toList
```